# Как убрать все тексты, которые не на русском языке в Python?

Tags: python

У меня есть список с текстами, но к сожалению они не только на русском, но и на других языках с кириллицей (например казахский). К сожалению программа с которой я работаю распознаёт только русский язык, поэтому мне нужно из этого списка убрать другие языки и оставить только тексты на русском. Написанная мною функция не приносит никаких результатов, поэтому я была бы благодарна, если бы кто-то подсказал как можно решить эту проблему.
Список текстов выглядит вот так:

```
tweets_text = ['Врачи оценили риск повторно заразиться при высоком титре антител', 'Харин сонин короно байх юм аа Ардын намын ойд очихгүй мөр…',]
```

Comment: в вопросе та функция, которую вы написали?

Comment: а что ваша функция вообще проверяет? почему в ней проверяется заведомо неверное условие?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно предложить разные варианты, вот я вам на основе библиотеки `pymorphy2` набросал:

```
#!pip install pymorphy2
from pymorphy2 import MorphAnalyzer
import pymorphy2
import re

m = MorphAnalyzer()
r = re.compile(r'\w\w+')
tweets_text = ['Врачи оценили риск повторно заразиться при высоком титре антител', 'Харин сонин короно байх юм аа Ардын намын ойд очихгүй мөр…',]

for tweet in tweets_text:
    cnt = 0
    bad = 0
    for word in r.findall(tweet):
        cnt += 1
        p = m.parse(word)[0]
        bad += (not p.tag.POS or \
               isinstance(p.methods_stack[0][0], pymorphy2.units.by_analogy.KnownSuffixAnalyzer.FakeDictionary))
    print(f'{bad/cnt:0.2f}', tweet)
```

Вывод:

```
0.00 Врачи оценили риск повторно заразиться при высоком титре антител
0.64 Харин сонин короно байх юм аа Ардын намын ойд очихгүй мөр…
```

Трактовка: чем ближе оценка к 0, тем вероятнее, что текст на русском языке (в нём больше слов, которые распознаются по словарю), а чем ближе к 1, тем вероятнее, что текст не на русском. Но вообще нужно проверять на ваших данных - есть языки, в которых слова сильно похожи на русские, так что границу отсечения вам нужно будет подобрать.

Суть проверки: если `pymorphy` вообще не смог определить часть речи у слова, либо если он воспользовался фейковым словарём для анализа, то плюс одно очко к тому, что слово не русское. В конце я делю набранные очки на кол-во слов в тексте.

Comment: Ваш скрип действительно выводит только русские тексты! Спасибо вам! Я хотела бы еще уточнить cnt  - это количество слов в тексте? И что означает 0.2? Если я хочу создать и сохранить новый список только с русскими текстами, то есть теми у которых оценка ближе к 0, то как можно это сделать? Если я просто приравняю к 0, то те которые немного больше 0 не попадут в этот список

Comment: @Kathi Да, cnt просто счётчик всех слов, а bad - счётчик скорее всего нерусских слов. Ну вот я об этом и написал в ответе, что вам порог отсечения нужно будет подобрать. `0.2` значит 2 нерусских слова из 10 в предложении. Надо подобрать границу, может это будет `0.25`, а может `0.15`, а может  `0.3` - я не знаю, нужно смотреть ваши примеры, которые попадают примерно на границу.

Comment: А так ну сделайте новый список и проверку `if bad/cnt < 0.25: new_list.append(tweet)` примерно так.

Comment: у меня выдаётся ошибка: ZeroDivisionError. Я попробовала исправить, но почему то выдается пустой список после моего исправления:   for word in r.findall(tweet):
        cnt += 1
        p = m.parse(word)[0]
        bad += (not p.tag.POS or \
               isinstance(p.methods_stack[0][0],pymorphy2.units.by_analogy.KnownSuffixAnalyzer.FakeDictionary))
    try:
        if bad/cnt < 0.25:
            only_russian_tweets.append(tweet)
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        continue

Comment: Видимо, попадаются твиты где вообще слов не находится, попробуйте начать подсчёт с `cnt = 1` вместо `cnt = 0`, ошибка должна уйти, а оценки не сильно изменятся. Но такие твиты вообще непонятно куда относить, к какому языку.

Comment: если я меняю на 1, то при итерации программа возвращает мне пустой список. Я думала что может при итерации программа сможет пропускать такие случаи и работать дальше, но мое решение с continue тоже не работает

Comment: Наоборот я хотела сказать. Если 1, то выводит и других языков тексты, а если 0 то пустой список

Comment: @Kathi Я имел в виду инициализацию счётчика в начале, мне кажется вы где-то не там меняете код. Я посмотрю, может допишу потом код, если вам непонятно, как его применять для фильтрации списка. И если можно добавьте в вопрос сомнительные твиты у которых скор не позволяет их однозначно отнести к русским или нет.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте пройтись по телу массива, по словам проверяя каждый символ на наличие его в русском алфавите

Пример кода :

```
text = ['Врачи оценили риск повторно заразиться при высоком титре антител', 'Харин сонин короно байх юм аа Ардын намын ойд очихгүй мөр…',]

rus = set('абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя ')
conv_text = lambda mas_in : [''.join([j for j in i if j.lower() in rus]) for i in mas_in]

print(conv_text(text))
```

Результат исполнения :

```
['Врачи оценили риск повторно заразиться при высоком титре антител', 'Харин сонин короно байх юм аа Ардын намын ойд очихгй мр']
```

Comment: К сожалению, у вас это не получится, так как  казахский язык в данном примере использует кириллицу, а это тот же алфавит что и в русском языке

Comment: Если верить Википедии, в казахском алфавите присутствуют буквы Ә ә,  І і, Ө ө, Ү ү, Һ һ, Ғ ғ, Қ қ. Ң ң, Ү́ ү́, Ұ ұ, Вот по их присутствию  и отсекайте казахские тексты.

Comment: @passant Я же написала в комментарии выше, что многие используют кириллицу как в примере выше в списке text. Если применить написанный скрипт выше, то программа выдаст снова эти два предложения и не уберет второе предложение из списка